# Why should i use Handlbars Templates in BackboneJS application instead of underscore templates?

Tags: backbone.js, handlebars.js, client-side-templating

I have seen many people using handlebars templates with BackboneJS instead of underscore templates, even underscore is hard dependency of BackboneJS. Can anyone please tell me benefits of doing so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Handlebars:

1. Compatible with mustache templates - what cam be used to use same syntax, or even templates
2. More readable syntax

Underscore:

1. No need to load extra library for template
2. Underscore its not only template engine. It has 80+ useful functions for working with objects, arrays and collections.

On my point of view there are a lot of advantages and disadvantages of using these libs according project specifics.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you are using and what you are needing a template for.

For example, like Evgeniy said, when you want to deal much with collections, such as SORT, or extracting a particular field's value (from a result set), extracting UNIQUE values ... these are the places where you will be better off using Underscore.

Going back to what Evgeniy said, I think it is those 80+ useful functions that make Underscore significant.

I prefer Handlebars for Templates, because I feel that handlebars is more readable and a bit less complex than Underscore when it comes to Template needs. Again, that's my preference.

But bottom-line is, I user Underscore for the Functions it provides and Handlebars for Templates.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Underscore provides the basic functions needed for any project and thats the advantage of that.

At the same time Handlebars can be efficiently used in a project which needs to do lot of formatting/ common functions with some set of data. For e.g. if a project has requirement of displaying a name in a specific format and has to be in sync across the application, then handlebars come in handy.

We can simply write a handlebar and call that function from all the places in the application.

In short i would say both are handy for development and they are wonderful in their own ways.

Hope i have not confused you :)